# Properties null when extending Whoops PrettyPageHandler

Tags: php, error-handling, whoops

Consider this simple child class of `PrettyPageHandler`

```
class NewErrorHandler extends \Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler
{
    public $foo = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->foo = 'bar';

        echo 'executed';
    }
}
```

When this is used like this:

```
$errorHandler = new NewErrorHandler();
$whoops->pushHandler($errorHandler);
$whoops->register();
var_dump($errorHandler->foo);
```

`$errorHandler->foo` is null but "executed" was printed. It seems `$this->foo = 'bar';` was not executed or nullified in the process even though it should've. Any ideas why?

**Update 1**

I'm trying to get the output of `handle();` via output buffering which works fine. But at the same time I want to set a var:

```
    public function handle()
    {           
        parent::handle();
        $output = ob_get_clean();

        echo 'executed';

        $this->foo = 'bar';
    }
```

`$this->foo = 'bar';` doesn't seem to get executed at this point but "executed" is printed.

**Update 2**

I'm trying to determine if the error is not yet logged, if true, do stuff like send notifications (e.g., email/sms/etc). If the error is already logged, it means it's duplicate, don't send notifications anymore. Here's a bit more code but simplified for clarity:

```
<?php

class NewErrorHandler extends \Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler
{
    private $errorHash;
    private $isNewError;    

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }    

    public function handle()
    {
        parent::handle();
        $output = ob_get_clean();

        $this->setErrorHash();

        if (!$this->isDuplicateError()) {

            $this->isNewError = true;

            $this->log($output);    
        }
    }

    private function log(string $data): void
    {
        $filename = $this->errorHash . '.html';   

        file_put_contents('logs/errors/'. $filename, $data);
    }

    public function isDuplicateError(): bool
    {
        // code check if the file $this->errorHash.'.html' exists in logs/errors/
        // ...
    }

    private function setErrorHash(): string
    {
        $ex = $this->getException();

        $this->errorHash = md5($ex->getMessage() . $ex->getFile() . $ex->getLine() . $ex->getTraceAsString());
    }
}

$errorHandler = new NewErrorHandler();
$whoops->pushHandler($errorHandler);
$whoops->register();
if ($errorHandler->isNewError == true)
{
     // do something like send notifications... outside the child class.
}
```

The issue is `$errorHandler->isNewError` is null even if it should be `true`

**Update 3:**

I'll try to explain my thinking on why this should work. Here's a basic example of what I'm trying to do. Let's pretend there's a simplified `Whoops` class called `FakeWhoops`

```
<?php

class FakeWhoops
{
    private $handler;

    public function pushHandler(CustomHandler $handler)
    {
        $this->handler = $handler;
    }

     public function triggerError()
    {
        $this->handler->handle();
    }
}
```

And this is my custom handler:

```
class CustomHandler
{
    public $foo;

    public function handle()
    {       
        $this->foo = true;
        echo 'executed';
    }
}
```

Now let's run it and trigger a fake error:

```
$cH = new CustomHandler;

$fW = new FakeWhoops;
$fW->pushHandler($cH);

// let's trigger a fake error which should call CustomHandler::handle();
$fW->triggerError();

var_dump($cH->foo); // returns true, foo was set!
```

As you can see here, this is exactly what I'm trying to do albeit using the real `Whoops`. It's the same simple idea. But why does this work on this simplified example but not with `Whoops`?

Comment: Isn't `handle()` what's outputting the error screen and only executed when an error occurs, and not when the handler is registered? In that case, `$errorHandler->foo` should be null at when you're trying to access it in the code above. If you want it to be set straight away, set it in the constructor instead. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I've updated the post for more info :)

Comment: In the code above, you're doing `var_dump($errorHandler->foo)` _before_ your `handle()`-method is executed. So you're first dumping the `foo`-property (which isn't set at this point), then an error occurs, `handle()` is executed which outputs "executed" and sets the `foo`-property. The code you've posted is pretty pointless, but if you actually explain what problem you're trying to solve, we might be able to help better.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Added more info (see update 2)

Comment: I'll try this again, any property you set in `handle()` won't be set until `handle()` is executed. In the above code, `handle()` haven't been executed when you do `if ($errorHandler->isNewError == true)`. `handle()` is _not_ executed when the handler is added/registered, it's executed when an error/exception occurs. You can therefor _not_ check those properties _before_ an error occurs. Also, if you want to send notifications when something happens, it should be done in your `NewErrorHandler`-class. That's what those are for.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sorry I am not getting it straight yet. So I am testing this on a deliberate error which means `NewErrorHandler->handle()` was executed, which is further verified by `$this->log();` because the log file was written. In other words, how come `$this->log();` was executed but not `$this->isNewError = true;` even if they are both inside `handle()`?

Comment: You're checking `$errorHandler->isNewError == true` _before_ the error is invoked and the `handle()`-method is executed. It's like doing: `echo $someVariable; $someVariable = 'Foo';`. You can't expect a variable to be set before you set it. And as I mentioned, there's no reason to handle the notifications outside of your error handler. Do that inside of the `handle()`-method in your class instead.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I get what you mean but the line `$this->isNewError = true;` was set inside`handle()` right? It means `$this->isNewError` was set. Didn't that line just ran when an error occurs because it's inside `handle()`? This is blowing my mind. You mean to say `$this->isNewError = true;` is being skipped when `handle()` is called?

Comment: In your code, you have the line `if ($errorHandler->isNewError == true) { ... }` in the line after `$whoops->register();`. At that point, `handle()` has not been executed and `$errorHandler->isNewError` will be unset. It's not until later, when the code hits the error the `handle()` will be executed and `isNewError` will be set. I'm not sure how I can explain it better.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Alright. Sorry if we seem to just repeat ourselves but how do you explain `$this->log($output);` being executed but not  `$this->isNewError = true;` even if they're both inside `handle()`?

Comment: How do you know it's not being executed? You're just setting the property to `true`, but you're not doing anything with it after it's set.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson if it's getting executed why can't I access it from the `$errorHandler` instance outside? It's the same `$errorHandler` instance that ran `handle()` therefore I should be able to access `$errorHandler->isNewError`. Isn't that how OOP is suppose to work?

Comment: Ok. Let's try this one  last time. This is your flow: 1. You instantiate `NewErrorHandler` (only `__construct()` is called). 2. You add it as a handler (`handle()` is _not_ executed). 3. You register whoops. (`handle()` is still not executed) 4. You're accessing `$errorHandler->isNewError` (at this point, `handler()` hasn't been executed = `isNewError` is null). 4. There's some error, _now_ `handle()` is executed, `isNewError` is set to true. Se the flow? Step 4 (your if-statement) comes _before_ step 5, where you set the `isNewError`. You're currently checking the property _before_ it's set.

Comment: Regardless if you're using OOP or not, the code is still executed in sequence.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You have two step 4's did you mean step 5.

Comment: Yes. It suppose to be: 5. There's some error, _now_ `handle()` is executed... It's been more than 5 minutes so I can't change the original comment.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Kindly see update 3 where I try to replicate what I deem should be happening.